# Rotating a system of points to obtain a point in a given place

Tags: 3d, rotations

Given an arbitrary number of points which lie on the surface of a unit sphere, one of which is arbitrarily `<0, 0, 1>` (which I will call **K**) in a rotated system (i.e. the rotation matrix is unknown), I'm trying to figure out how to (un-)rotate it so that the given point is `<0, 0, 1>` in the origin system.

The original method I came up with is to find the angle between the x and z components of **K** and rotating around the y-axis by that value:

```
double yrot = Math.atan2(point[0], point[2]);
for (int i = 0; i < p0.length; i++) {
    double[] p = p0[i];
    p0[i][0] = p[0] * Math.cos(theta) - p[2] * Math.sin(theta);;
    p0[i][2] = p[0] * Math.sin(theta) + p[2] * Math.cos(theta);
}
```

Then to find the angle between the y and z components of **K** and rotating around the x-axis by that value:

```
double xrot = Math.atan2(point[1], point[2]);
for (int i = 0; i < p0.length; i++) {
    double[] p = p0[i];;
    p0[i][1] = p[1] * Math.cos(theta) - p[2] * Math.sin(theta);
    p0[i][2] = p[1] * Math.sin(theta) + p[2] * Math.cos(theta);
}
```

This works great except for one issue: The magnitude of any of the points are no longer 1.

Where am I going wrong here?

---

In the above code blocks, `p0` refers to the system of points while `point` refers to **K**.

Comment: Just find the rotation that takes the given point to $(0,0,1)$ and invert it.

Comment: @Ross: That's what I'm trying to find how to do.

Comment: I think rotating the angle across two grid planes will cause your magnitude to be off by a factor of $ \sqrt{2} $ or $ \sqrt{3} $ or something. Is that the case?

Comment: @WaleedKhan: I haven't found any correlation between how much they are off by. Each point seems to gain it's own unique magnitude.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how I did it, but I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the vector $K$ and knowing that it corresponds to $(0,0,1)$ the rotation matrix can be obtained by taking the cross product $M = K\times(0,0,1)$, this yields a vector perpendicular to both $K$ and $(0,0,1)$, so that you can rotate by the angle between $K$ and $(0,0,1)$ around vector $M$. For that, expression [in this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle), will do.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than what I came up with! Thank you! I would up-vote your answer, but I can't yet.

Comment: @radar33 thanks, I found myself asking that question before. I'm glad it was useful. A bit late, but thanks.